# Can't get server up and running digitalocean / django

Tags: django, nginx, web-deployment, digital-ocean

I am very confused about how to set up my server because nothing seems to be working right. (I am a novice to all this)

I have the domain name dreamof.science with the registrar alp names. I have cloud hosting through digitalocean.

On digital ocean I have a droplet with nginx and django installed on my server through ssh on a secondary user (not root). There is an app I started from a book I am reading that teaches you django added onto it through my github in the directory sites/stratosphere.dreamof.science/source/django

I have been reading about this for days and the more I read the more I get confused. A records, AAA records, CNAMEs, PTR records, subdomains...I just want to know how the heck to get this server up and my app to run.

On my registrar I have my name servers pointed to the ones that digital ocean gave me for dreamof.science xx1.digitalocean.com xx2 etc.... On my registrar it also says I have 2 A records which all point to the same IP address which is the IP of my droplet. dreamof.science www.dreamof.science

I also have a CNAME to stratosphere.dreamof.science I am under the impression that this is my subdomain because you're not supposed to run apps on the regular domain....or something like that. Hence why I have my files in stratosphere.dreamof.science and nginx server config pointing towards stratosphere.dreamof.science

Now when I go to dreamof.science it just says "this webpage is unavailable." Same thing with stratosphere.dreamof.science and even when I just go directly to the server IP nothing shows up. I have the server running through the console on digital ocean and the droplet is active.
What is wrong here?

Comment: It's totally fine to run an app on a primary domain...That's basically every site in the world.

Comment: That's great to know but I still can't even get the primary domain to work :(

Comment: Can you show relevant parts of your nginx config? Are you using Django `runserver` or something like `gunicorn`?

Comment: Please see my responses to the first answer so far, thanks

Answer (score 0):

First, try creating a basic (empty) Django project in somewhere like `/var/www/myproject`. Start a debug server on port 8000 that accepts all connections using the `runserver` command like so:

```
python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

Then navigate to http://dreamof.science:8000/ and see if you return a successful debug screen. That will tell you if the domain resolves correctly.

Now try setting a basic Nginx config, similar to the following:

```
server {
    server_name dreamof.science;
    listen 80;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8000;
    }
}
```

Make sure that you don't have a firewall set to reject connections on that port.

Now try visiting http://dreamof.science/ to see if Nginx is running and set up to proxy the root domain to port 8000.

Comment: Ok so I did get the new server to run @ http://dreamof.science:8000/ but after adding the nginx config I still cannot go to dreamof.science   DigitalOcean says all ports are open by default

Comment: After adding the nginx file which I type exactly as you put it under the name dreamof.science I made a symlink and then restarted nginx. Then I went back to the new project and did python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000 again and the 8000 port works but if I just do dreamof.science it says the page cannot be found

Comment: Added some additional nginx config settings. I thought it might work without them, but possibly not.